# In App Subscriptions in Android

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I am still looking for third party "in-App billing and subscriptions mechanism" but It would be worth taking your point of view on this.

I looked into "Google Checkout Beta Features" (http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_Beta_Features.html) but it is in beta stage, Do we have other reliable alternatives for android market which could serve the monthly subscription.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can now support in app subscriptions:
If you have done in app purchasing of products before it's not much of a change, have to check for version 2 of the billing/vending though.

See the android developer blog:

http://android-developers.blogspot.se/2012/05/in-app-subscriptions-in-google-play.html

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at PayPal's [Mobile Payment Library](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/products/mobile-payment-libraries). I'm not sure how well it supports subscriptions, though.